# 1993 Ford Probe GT that has no spark and can't hear fuel pump kick in?

Tags: ford, starting, fuel-system, spark

I had this car for three days.  On the first day it was perfect and then the second day it just stopped out of no where. I started it up and it kept doing it every now and then until it never started up any more.

I now have no spark and no fuel.

What is the problem?

Comment: Is there any more information you can add to the post?  How did you test for spark?  Have you tested your fuel pump?  Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Comment: will first i thought it was only the fuel pump and i replaced it and it still wouldn't start.. and then my buddy looked at her. i dont know how he tested it. and thanks

Comment: Do you have a mutlimeter so you can test for 12 volts at the fuel pump hot lead?

Comment: yes i do.. ill try that, and i was also wondering could it be the ignition?

Comment: Pull a spark plug out of the head.  Put it on the lead wire and ground it on your valve cover.  If you can turn over the motor and see if you have spark you can either rule that in or out as an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the Probe in particular, but I know some cars have a crankshaft position sensor that tells the ECU that the engine is turning over, and they won't turn on the fuel pump if they aren't getting a signal from that sensor. I'd also recommend checking your relays. Since it was an intermittent fault I'd suspect relays before fuses, but fuses can become cracked and intermittent too, especially if they're old. You might want to try swapping any fuses related to the fuel pump or ECU if there are any other fuses in the block that have the same rating.